# Anomaly foundd using UNION ALL, GROUP BY, using subquery

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, teradata, union-all

Well, I'm pretty new on teradata, but I'm pretty sure I can understand this simple logic, except I took the logic wrong, so here's the case :

I have one table in Teradata database with some records in it, this record was imported daily from txt file given by userA, for some reason I decided to extract the exact same data from userA server directly without waiting for userA giving his txt file. But before I insert the data that I extract directly from the server, ofc I have to compare both data first, whether they equal or not with the data that I usually get daily from txt file.

Then I decided to so UNION ALL and GROUP BY inside a subquery, using this logic, say called it logic1:

```
Select Col1, Col2,..., ColN, Count(*) 
From (
Txt_file UNION ALL server_file) 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,...,N
```

Ofc, If both records from txtfile and serverfile are the same, it will return for every group count equal 2 right?? Because I have check it there are no any duplicates for each txtfile and serverfile, so if there are any duplicates there it will only occur if and only if both txtfile and serverfile UNION ALL-ish.

But, I got 1 group with count(*) equals 1, how come? The when I check the records by its value, like I said I found exactly the same 1 record from txt, and also 1 record from serverfile, but why it didn't return 2 when I do the logic1?

Not to mention I even got another 1 group with count(*) equals 3,meanwhile when I check the same record from txtfile, I found 1, and another 1 record from serverfile, but why It return 3,no idea at all.

Did I miss something?

the query I used :

```
SEL OREPLACE( CAST(THIRDREIMBUSBIC AS VARCHAR(100)),' ',''), OREPLACE( CAST(ACCTCOVER AS VARCHAR(100)),' ',''), OREPLACE( CAST(VALUEDATE AS VARCHAR(100)),' ',''), OREPLACE( CAST(CURRENCYPO AS VARCHAR(100)),' ',''), OREPLACE( CAST(AMOUNTPO AS VARCHAR(100)),' ',''), OREPLACE( CAST(CUSTID AS VARCHAR(100)),' ',''), COUNT(*) 
FROM (
        sel * from  servertable where cast(settledate as date format 'dd/mm/yyyy') = '06/12/2020'
        union all
        sel * from txttable where start_date = date-5) A
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

The result I got :

```
THIRDREIMBUSBIC | ACCTCOVER | VALUEDATE | CURRENCYPO | AMOUNTPO | CUSTID | COUNT(*)
?   972981  2020-12-06  IDR 1838600.00  ?   3
?   972981  2020-12-06  IDR 6329600.00  ?   1
```

The result I expected :

```
THIRDREIMBUSBIC | ACCTCOVER | VALUEDATE | CURRENCYPO | AMOUNTPO | CUSTID | COUNT(*)
?   972981  2020-12-06  IDR 1838600.00  ?   2
?   972981  2020-12-06  IDR 6329600.00  ?   2
```

Comment: Hard to say without the actual data. You will get 3 when there are duplicate rows in one of the input tables. If two rows look the same, but are not treated the same by groupmby, there might be an invisible difference, e.g. a character which only looks like a space, but is actually something different. Btw, to find unique rows you might use `select * from t1 except select * from tab2` and vice versa

Comment: Somehow I couldnt post the data due to confusion, what exactly should I post, but I assume, you meant I did miss something, like youve said spaces, or anything related to not visible by human eyes, but visible by system. Thats why before I do the union all, I have convert all the records into varchar, afterwards I use the function OREPLACE to omit all the soaces that can be found, I even do LOWER function to convert all the records into the same lowercase.

Comment: This will probably not help, as Standard SQL/Teradata ignores trailings spaces and your table is probably crated with NOT CASESPECIFIC char columns. Additionally the data types in both columns are probably the same. When you found the bad rows you might apply CHAR2HEXINT to the string columns.

Comment: yes, the table was created with type CHARACTER NOT CASESPESIFIC, meanwhile other was like DATE, BIGINIT, DECIMAL, please kindly see my updated question, I've provided the sample code, well it is like my 99% code, except for I have masking the tablenames, the value of ACCTCOVER, and I have filter 2 output which is the anomaly one from total 3337 output , meanwhile this (3337-2) output got count(*)  equals 2 as I expected (1 comes from serverfile, 1 comes from txtfile).

Comment: my confusion was, how come the count(*) goes to 3 meanwhile the data that satisfy those value of 6 column is only 2 records, and the other output reduced to 1 record meanwhile it should be also 2 records.

Comment: Try to materialize the bad rows before aggregation in a new table and check if it still return that 3/1 count. If you think it's a wrong result, open an incident with Teradata support.